# How to properly delete multidemensional vector?

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array, memory-leaks

So I am creating two different multidimensional vectors like this below

```
string **customdiceArray = new string*[crows];
for(unsigned int i = 0; i<crows;i++){
    customdiceArray[i] = new string[ccolumns];
}
```

They are giving me memory leaks however. I do a delete call like the one below for both vectors. Where am i going wrong?

```
//Deallocate create objects
delete diceArray;
diceArray = 0;

//set<string>* words = new set<string>;
delete words;
words = 0;

//string **customdiceArray = new string*[crows];
delete customdiceArray;
customdiceArray = 0;
```

Comment: these are arrays. not vectors.

Comment: You have to loop over the array deleting each element, then delete the array.

Comment: Like this: `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> dice(crows, std::vector<std::string>(ccolumns));`

Comment: Good C++ programs contain almost no `delete` statements. If you actually used `vector` instead of arrays your code would be simpler and correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want use delete in proper way here some examples:

For one variable

```
string *i = new string;
delete i;
```

For arrays (one dimension)

```
string *i = new string[10];
delete[] i;
```

For arrays (multi dimensions)

```
string **i = new *string[10]
for(int j=0; j<10;++j){
   i[j] = new string[10];
}

for(int j=0; j<10;++j){
   delete[] i[j];
}
delete[] i;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ardel. That solved my memory leak!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid memory leaks and write C++ native code, you can also use std::vector instead of C arrays which needs more caution and maintenance.

for example:

```
vector<vector<int> > matrix;

vector<int> cols;
cols.push_back(1);
cols.push_back(2);
cols.push_back(3);

matrix.push_back(cols);
matrix.push_back(cols);

for(int i=0; i<matrix.size(); i++)
  for(int j=0; j<cols.size(); j++)
    cout << matrix[i][j] << endl;
```

Result:

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
```